# Electron & Angular - get path of <input> file field

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron, fs

Is there a way to get the file path of the file that the user has uploaded?

I have this input field (Angular):

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input #select type="file" class="form-control" id="inputGroupFile02" (change)="readFile(select)" accept=".txt">
    <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupFile02">Upload</label>
</div>
```

I'm able to get the file name and its content this way:

```
async readFile(select: HTMLInputElement) {
 this.fileToUpload = select?.files?.item(0) || null;

 const formData: FormData = new FormData();
 if (this.fileToUpload) {
   formData.set("name", this.fileToUpload.name);
   formData.set("file", await this.fileToUpload.text().then(fileContent => {
     return fileContent
   }));
  }
```

Is there a way I can get the file path so that i can store it in a database? I could only manage to get "fakepath/fileName" and I know that this is done for security reason, but there's a secure way to get the path? (Maybe with some NodeJS API?! I tried to see if I could do it using the fs module but i didn't find anything useful). Thank you.

Comment: where are you uploading a file? in local folder in node or s3 bucket

Comment: @PK2995 in a local folder

Comment: then  file path is hostname + path you storing in nodejs  for example
node folder - uploads then your location of URL

http://localhost:3000/uploads/file-1550484364038.png 

if  you deployed in host use domain name instead of localhost

http://fileupload.com/uploads/file-1550484364038.png